# FILE is not a member of FILE Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

> Error 1   'JonesA06HO' is not a member of
>   'JonesA06HO'. C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\JonesA06HO - Copy\JonesA06HO\My
>   Project\Application.Designer.vb   35  27  JonesA06HO

```
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            **Me.MainForm = Global.JonesA06HO.JonesA06HO**
        End Sub
```

I am getting the error that JonesA06HO is not a member of JonesA06HO in my VB application. Can someone tell me how to solve this issue? It appears to be an issue with the above snipper of code. I have bolded the Me.MainForm section - What do I need to do to make my JonesA06HO file function?

Comment: VB6 does not have a `<Global.System.Diagnostics>` namespace. This is VB.NET, and they are not the same. Choosing proper tags is important, so that people who are familiar with the topic you're asking about see it (and people who are not can not waste their time with it).

Comment: Also, there's no error here related to `FILE` anywhere, so what makes you think it has to do with a `FILE`? You're referencing a namespace member `Global.JonesA06H0.JonesA06H0` that doesn't exist. What makes you think you should set `Me.MainForm` to that value?

Comment: Because Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition automatically set that and JonesA06HO DOES exist. It is in the Solution Explorer as JonesA06HO.vb...?

Comment: Edit your question, and add the declaration (from `JonesA06H0.vb`) starting with the line that says `namespace` and the next line that starts with `partial class`, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = JonesA06HO.BillingForm
```

The file must reference the form. So even though JonesA06HO DOES EXIST; it requires a . and the name of the form itself.

If any one stumbles onto this; I hope it helps them.